# How to request specific version of R package to be available on conda repo?

Tags: r, anaconda, package

The highest version of `r` on https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64/ is 3.6.0, is there a way to request version 3.6.3 to be available there?
(Due to framework setup at my workplace we cannot connect to CRAN and have to rely on packages available on conda repo).

Comment: Is [Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base/files) not allowed? It hosts everything from CRAN that I've ever needed.

Comment: This puzzles me; when I do `conda search r` I can not find version 3.6.3.

Comment: `conda search -c conda-forge r-base`. Generally, if you use Conda for R, I recommend [adding **conda-forge** to your global channel configuration](https://conda-forge.org/#about).

Comment: Thanks @merv I was searching for `r` instead of `r-base`. I tried `r-base` before but always end up a long running "Finding conflicts ..." process which leads to a failure, so I try to avoid it if possible. Anyway I think I have a workaround: updating python from 3.7.5 to 3.8 somehow resolves it and finally pleases conda to proceed installation.

Comment: I strongly recommend creating new environments for R. Modularizing environments to specific tasks and projects helps reduce solving complexity.